# Why does $\frac{x}{\ln x}$ tend to infinity faster than $x^a$ for $a < 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I can see why $\displaystyle \frac{x}{\ln x}$ tends to infinity more slowly than $x$ (and for any power of $x$ that's greater than 1). However, I don’t know why it tends to infinity more rapidly than $x^a$ for $a < 1$ (where $a$ is a positive number I suppose).

Apparently this follows from the fact that $\displaystyle \frac{\ln x}{x^\delta} \to 0$ for every positive $\delta$. For reference, I was reading page 10 of Hardy & Wright’s *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*. They also remark that $x/\ln(x)$ is "the simplest function which has this property". Do you know what they meant by "simplest"?

Comment: We have $$\frac{{x^\alpha  }}{{\frac{x}{{\log x}}}} = \frac{{\log x}}{{x^{1 - a} }} \to 0$$ as $x\to +\infty$ since $0 < 1 - a$ by assumption. I am guessing they mean that $\log x$ is the simplest elementary function that grows slower than any positive power.

Comment: I see... I didn't think to divide those two functions. Thanks!

Comment: @Gary: You could post that as an answer so it can be accepted and the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\frac{{x^\alpha  }}{{\frac{x}{{\log x}}}} = \frac{{\log x}}{{x^{1 - a} }} \to 0$$ as $x\to +\infty$ since $0< 1 - a$ by assumption. I am guessing they mean that $\log x$ is the simplest elementary function that grows slower than any positive power.

Answer (score 2):

You want to show that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x/\log x}{x^a}=\infty
$$
This is the same as
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{1-a}}{\log x}
$$
Since $a<1$, we have $1-a>0$, so the numerator has limit $\infty$. Now substitute $y=x^{1-a}$ and the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{y\to\infty}(1-a)\frac{y}{\log y}
$$
This should explain why “simplest” is used in the referenced text.

Comment: Hi, sorry, but I'm not sure why that might explain the use of the word "simplest". Do you mean it is because the ratio of $x/\log x$ to $x^a$ can be expressed as a constant times $y/\log y$ (where $y = x^{1-a}$)? That the ratio simplifies to a simple expression that refers back to (in fact, is proportional to) the original function $x/\log x$?